# How to copy in node Dockerfile (folders both in container)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

*This is different than questions about copying from host to container.*

I'm trying to copy the build folder to the nginx html folder. I don't know what copy command I should use, as `cp` didn't work.

My dockerfile segment (see the `RUN` copy command which isn't working)

```
FROM node:12.14.1 # If syntax is off, please ignore

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN rm -rf node_modules &&\
    npm ci &&\
    npm run build # MAKES BUILD IN /app/build

# set up html files
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN cp /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html # BROKEN - HOW TO COPY STATIC FILES HERE?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a recursive copy?

`RUN cp -r /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html`

(Assuming the destination folder already exists. Add a `RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html` line before copying the files if it does not.)

Comment: The error origionally was Step 8/10 : RUN cp /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> Running in badae7f34196
cp: omitting directory '/app/build'
The command '/bin/sh -c cp /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html' returned a non-zero code: 1 
so I think you're right and I didn't even realize that's what the error meant. Trying it now

Comment: Let me know how it goes! `n____n`